# Card not passing imageProps to image component

Tags: react-native

I'm using the `Card` component from `react-native-elements` and it says in the documentation I can pass `imageProps` to the `image`, and that `imageProps` can be anything that `Image` from `react-native` can accept.

So, what I have is:

```
   <Card
      key={post._id}
      title={post.title}
      imageStyle={{
        height: 300
      }}
      imageProps={{
        ImageComponent: (
          <ImagePlaceholder
            src={post.image.location}
            placeholder={post.image.location}
            duration={1000}
            showActivityIndicator={true}
            activityIndicatorProps={{
              size: "large",
              color: index % 2 === 0 ? "blue" : "red"
            }}
          />
        )
      }}
      image={{ uri: post.image.location }}
    >..........................................
```

The problem here, is that `ImagePlaceholder` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-with-placeholder)) doesn't render. Instead, the image just fades into the `Card` when it is downloaded. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does the `ImagePlaceholder` even work anywhere in your app at all?

Comment: Yup. It just doesn't work here.